# Limit the memory allocation in Go Language?

Tags: go

I'm finding a way to limit the memory usage in Go language. My application implementing with Go language has a big data that must be loaded in main memory, so I want to limit the maximum memory size of the process to the size specified by the user.

In C language, actually, I accumulate the sizes of malloc'ed memory to do that, but I don't know how to do same thing in Go language.

Please let me know if there is a way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to find a way to limit memory usage, am I correct? Not that you're reaching the memory limits of go (if there are any). Just solidifying the facts here.

Comment: Is the "big data" a file? In such a case I'd recommend using mmap() instead of reading the whole file in to memory at once.

Comment: See also Go 1.19 (Q4 2022) [new `SetMemoryLimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72103637/6309).

Comment: About the usage of `SetMemoryLimit`, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70831114/3011380

Answer (score 4):

The Go garbage collector is not deterministic and it is conservative. Therefore, using the [runtime.MemStats](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStatsType) variable is not going to be accurate for your purpose.

Fix your approximate memory usage by setting the maximum size of data that you are going to allow to be loaded at one time into a process using the input from the user.

Comment: Its low accuracy is not problem for me only if it is updated atomically. So I have been finding whether or not it is atomic, but I've not found how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) in conjunction with your go code?

Comment: What happens after the allocated memory size reaches to the limited size?

Comment: out of memory error? Just a shot in the dark.. But it seemed like a tool you could possibly use.

Comment: Sadly out of memory in Go means runtime panic. But that may what one wants.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [runtime/debug.SetMemoryLimit](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/debug#SetMemoryLimit)

Answer (score 0):

Besides [runtime.MemStats](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStatsType) you could use [gosigar](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gosigar) to monitor system memory.