# Increase Heap size in GO

Tags: go, garbage-collection

Is there a way howto instruct GO runtime to use larger heaps? I am running `GO 1.5`.

My GO process is currently spending 34% of time in GC but it uses unly 1/3 of available systems memory.

I know `ulimit` can be used to limit max heap size. I have set ulimit to ~16GB (`ulimit -v 17179869184`) but the heap size never goes over 5GB.

Using `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` I can see high GC overhead (34%):

```
20160719-220359.169294 :: gc 665 @5484.983s 34%: 3.3+2504+188+1635+8.0 ms clock, 26+2504+0+26950/3271/3.5+64 ms cpu, 4825->4964->2623 MB, 4948 MB goal, 8 P
20160719-220406.322354 :: gc 666 @5492.411s 34%: 2.9+212+2111+1749+8.3 ms clock, 23+212+0+25010/3496/146+67 ms cpu, 4846->4990->2657 MB, 4970 MB goal, 8 P
20160719-220413.703514 :: gc 667 @5499.452s 34%: 4.4+4411+0.021+0.25+8.4 ms clock, 35+4411+0+29365/0.054/38+67 ms cpu, 4908->5022->2618 MB, 5025 MB goal, 8 P
```

Comment: Sounds like `ulimit` is the right setting to change. According to this discussion it's not cross platform though https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9849 so that might be why it's not working for you.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that discussion but that is only in the context of limiting GO to use "max up to a certain limit". In my case, I have set the limit to be 16GB but the process' heap never get even close to that max limit.

Comment: First, please start with a current version of Go, either 1.6.x or the current 1.7 RCs. there have been a lot of changes that might help. If you want go to use more heap between collections, increase GOGC, which starts off at 100 by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade to 1.6 yet, the affected production stack is currently running 1.5.

Comment: GOGC is a percentage, can it be set to higher than 100?

Comment: Yes, you can set GOGC higher, try 400 and see what happens. I don't recall exactly what the gctrace timings in go1.5 are, but I think it looks like most of your time is in the concurrent scan, so it shouldn't be impacting you too greatly. This is expected if you have a very large number of pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control this with the `GOGC` environment variable.
It is a percentage: set it to 200 and the Go runtime will use twice as much memory as before.

[this was buried in the comments; I'm making it visible as an answer]

Update: there is a detailed discussion of different techniques at https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23044, including mention of the "ballast" technique.

Comment: good article about "ballast" to increase the heap allocating a very big slice https://blog.twitch.tv/go-memory-ballast-how-i-learnt-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-heap-26c2462549a2

Comment: This is amazing engineering @martinezdelariva , by far the most mind blowing technique i have read recently.

updated blog link:
https://blog.twitch.tv/en/2019/04/10/go-memory-ballast-how-i-learnt-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-heap/

Answer (score 3):

The Golang documentation describes GOGC:

> The GOGC variable sets the initial garbage collection target
> percentage. A collection is triggered when the ratio of freshly
> allocated data to live data remaining after the previous collection
> reaches this percentage. The default is GOGC=100. Setting GOGC=off
> disables the garbage collector entirely.

There is an optimal value for GOGC, and it depends on the application and system that you run the Go application on. You can read more in this [blog](https://blog.cloudflare.com/go-dont-collect-my-garbage/) and this [one](https://concertio.com/2020/06/18/optimizing-the-go-garbage-collector-and-concurrency/).

You can try different values and see the effects on performance, or use a free tool like [Optimizer Studio](https://optimizer.concertio.com) that will find the optimal GOGC value automatically.

Answer (score 2):

> I know `ulimit` can be used to limit max heap size

Actually, starting possibly Go 1.19 (Q4 2022), this won't be the only way.

From [`golang/go` issue 48409 "Proposal: Soft memory limit"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48409) (which just landed in May 2022, with [commit f01c20b](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/f01c20bf2ba889e5c9e3565175cc4276f9c11516), implementing its [design document](https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/48409-soft-memory-limit.md))

> new option for tuning the behavior of the Go garbage collector by setting a soft memory limit on the total amount of memory that Go uses.
>
> This option comes in two flavors:
>
> - a new `runtime/debug` function called `SetMemoryLimit` and
> - a `GOMEMLIMIT` environment variable.
>
> In sum, the runtime will try to maintain this memory limit by limiting the size of the heap, and by returning memory to the underlying platform more aggressively.
> This includes with a mechanism to help mitigate garbage collection death spirals.
>
> **Finally, by setting `GOGC=off`, the Go runtime will always grow the heap to the full memory limit.**
>
> This new option gives applications better control over their resource economy. It empowers users to:
>
> - Better utilize the memory that they already have,
> - Confidently decrease their memory limits, knowing Go will respect them,
> - Avoid unsupported forms of garbage collection tuning.

---

[`golang/go` issue 58106](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58106) clearly states:

> An alternative to increasing `GOMEMLIMIT` is to switch to a `GOGC`-based GC trigger once you get close to the limit.
> This is effectively just a softer limit, but defined in terms of memory rather than CPU usage (which may be less noisy).
>
> You can calculate the "effective" `GOGC` value at any given time like so:
>
> `(/gc/heap/goal:bytes) / (/gc/heap/live:bytes + /gc/scan/stack:bytes + /gc/scan/globals:bytes) * 100 - 100`
>
> and compare that against your target minimum `GOGC`, say for example 10. If that value ever goes below 10, set `SetGCPercent` to 10 and set `GOMEMLIMIT` back to `MaxInt64`.